# How does paypal notify you of billing plan payments?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

After a couple of hours, I managed to figure out how normal single payments flow works on Paypal. However, I am struggling to wrap my head around billing plans.

I know how to instantiate a billing plan/agreement. What I cannot understand however is how will I know if the user stopped paying and how to renew the user's subscription? What kind of signalling should I expect?

1. Will paypal notify me after every payment?
2. Will paypal notify me if a user cancelled the billing plan/agreement?
3. Should I have like a cron-job that checks whether users witha subscription plan need to renew.

It's really confusing and I can't find any part of the documentations touching on this issue.